# How to Browser Cache a set of results in Python GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, browser-cache

I have been spending a lot of time trying to figure out a way to do this, and I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.  I have built a google app engine that helps people codify reports.  The codes they use are pretty static, though there will need to be checks to make sure there is an update to the code base.  The thing is, I would like to store the codes in the browser cache so that I don't need to do a round trip to the server, which then filters the results.  If I am able to keep it in the browser cache, it will be significantly faster load, not constantly pinging the db for the results, especially if the user changes what the autotext start is.

Any ideas?  Is there a better way?

thanks!

Comment: have you looked at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache DB Caching? document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser cache caches static resources (i.e. files) - html, css, images, etc. It is not intended for arbitrary data.

You have two options to store the data you need: cookies and HTML5 local storage, with local storage being a preferred way for your use case. You can get more information here: [Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)